# Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, npm

I'm getting this error while running `npm install` on project. The additional information about this issue below,

```
npm ERR! node-sass@0.9.6 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/capricornus/Projects/aware-app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Just install older version of Nodejs with nodebrew.

```
curl -L git.io/nodebrew | perl - setup
```

Add the following to ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
```

Refresh console

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install older version

```
nodebrew install-binary v0.12.7
nodebrew use v0.12.7
```

Then try again!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this version is no longer compatible. I get the same errors on my system. Either you need to downgrade node to the supported version, or upgrade the dependencies that require `node-sass@0.9.6`.

Latest version of node-sass is 3.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into trouble with nodebrew, it's also possible to use nvm (node version manager) to downgrade your node version. [Project on Github](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

On OSX El Capitan, I needed this for the installation:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Mind the last line, as it's slightly different from the install instruction on github.

As mentioned by Yosuke Sato, v0.12.7 is compatible with node-sass@0.9.6, so you'd need

```
nvm install v0.12.7 or nvm use v0.12.7 (if you have it installed already)
```

This will use the older node version, but only in the **current terminal window/tab**.

Answer (score 0):

`nvm use v0.12.7` in the project directory followed by `npm install` solved the problem for me -- the error occurred as I was trying to set up broccoli-taco, a static site generator. Thanks for tip, I am glad I googled you up.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you! Consider upvoting my answer or adding a comment, answers are merely ment to the "raw" solutions.